# VBA array length depending on a user input

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I wish to create a simple VBA array of doubles, but I want the array to have a length that is specified by a worksheet's cell value.

I try to do:

```
Dim NIteration As Integer: NIteration = ActiveSheet.Cells(16, 2).Value

Dim myArray(1 To NIteration) As Double
```

It fails with this error: "requires constant expression"

Comment: I think this will work `Dim myArray(NIteration) as Double` . If not Phil has a complete detail.

Comment: Tested, that does not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you want to make use of VB's `Redim` keyword.

Redim allows you to redefine the size of the array at runtime to a given upper bound.

**Dynamic array variables**

Dynamic array variables are useful when you in advance don’t know how many elements that you need to store information about.

You declare dynamic array variables just like a static array variable, except that you don’t give any information about the array size.

As an example, if you have:

```
Dim SheetNames(1 to 10) As String
```

an error will be thrown if the number of sheets exceeds 10 since SheetNames will not able to store more than 10 items in the collection.

Instead we use the `redim` keyword as below:

```
Sub Test()
  Dim MyArray() As String ' declare an array
  Dim iCount As Integer
  Dim Max As Integer
  Max = ActiveSheet.Cells(16, 2).Value ' finds the maximum array size

  ReDim MyArray(1 To Max) ' redeclares the array variable with the necessary size

  For iCount = 1 To Max
    MyArray(iCount) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(iCount).Name ' (or whatever you're storing in the array)
    MsgBox MyArray(iCount)
  Next iCount

  Erase MyArray() ' deletes the variable contents
End Sub
```